# Как конвертировать файл с формата .wav в .m4a в nodejs

Tags: node.js

Я скачиваю файл  и мне нужно его конвертнуть в .m4a, для nodejs найти ничего не могу. 
Есть какие-то варианты?
Если да то пример дайте пж.

Comment: node.js для таких вещей совсем не годится. Обязательно ноду использовать?

Comment: Запустить из ноды ffmpeg, например

Answer (score 0):

посмотрите в сторону этого модуля ffmpeg

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg

но он сам по себе будет вызывать через CLI ffmpeg который уже будет заниматся конвертированием